# What type of operation is needed when passing values through a form or an URL in php?

Tags: php

I saw some sites where it's showing using htmlspecialchars() and urlencode() but I am not able to understand how?

Comment: Could you add more information, especially what you want to intend to do? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Answer (score -1):

If you want passing values to url  use `GET` method on `action` in forms.
But it is very danger when you use some sensitive date.Better method is use `POST` the all data will be send without additions in url